# Load MySQL timezone tables

Tags: mysql, centos

trying to load the MySQL timezone tables, read many related posts here and the MySQL docs and can't find solution my problem.  I connect SSH via PUTTY as root and issue this command:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

I get these errors:

```
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those aren't errors.  They're warnings, and you can disregard them.  Your time zone tables should be populated, despite these warnings.

---

The utility being used in the question is a script bundled with MySQL Server called [`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).  It reads your Linux (or FreeBSD, Solaris, or macOS) system's time zone database and creates SQL statements from the information it discovers, that will load the time zone tables in MySQL.

The warnings are about time zones the utility found on the system that it doesn't recognize as containing usable time zone info.

The documentation [also mentions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) a pre-built file you can use, with the caveat that using this may mean that some time zones may not be an exact match for those on your system... so if you are doing time zone conversions both inside of MySQL and out, there could be inconsistencies, since time zones do occasionally change.

Comment: Thanks.  Another note from host was "Our default setup does not require the MySQL root password when running MySQL commands from the root user.  So you do not need the "-u root" when logged in as root."

Comment: That's always true if `root@localhost` has no password, but it doesn't actually make any difference in this case.  Using it, or omitting it, doesn't change anything.

Comment: This page is a top google result for people looking up "How to populate the time zone tables in mysql." If possible please share some instruction on how to do it or at least link to a site that does.

Comment: The original poster's command to load time zone data into MySQL is the correct one to use. More information is [available in the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html).